# CancellableFormController and 2 submit buttons

Tags: html, spring-mvc

It seems that my CancellableFormController picks the first of the 2 submit buttons' action if Enter is pressed on the form.

i.e. if my successView is success.jsp and cancelView is cancel.jsp and on my form Cancel button appears before Register, cancel.jsp is called when I hit enter.

Why is this happening. Code for my buttons is:

<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="<spring:message code="submit.cancel"/>"/>
<input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="submit.register"/>"/>

Can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate submit buttons in your jsp does not mean that your controller will perform differently based on that.

The thing here is whenever you submit any of the button it will perform the same action defined in the form tag.

You need to have two separate forms for each submit button and they must have the separate actions defined in it.

Comment: My form has no action. It just reads <form:form> and has the 2 submit buttons in it.